How does personal Confession work from a Reformed Perspective?
My question is pastoral in nature; I apologize if it seems naive. I am leaving Catholicism and transitioning to the Reformed Church's perspective, but there are still things I do not fully understand.
I understand that confession can be communal during the worship service. But I also understand that there is space for personal confession. What happens when I sin and want to ask God for forgiveness? Is contrition and a sincere confession enough? What are the elements that constitute a good personal confession before the Lord?
Thanks in advance.

If we confess our sins, he is faithful and just to forgive us our sins, and to cleanse us from all unrighteousness. If we say that we have not sinned, we make him a liar, and his word is not in us. 1 John 1:9,10 KJV.

There is an overlooked universal truth regarding how God deals with sin today that should help our view of confession:
God is not imputing sin to anyone today.
Our sins were left in the ground with Christ's shed blood for the "forgiveness of sin".  This is the foundation of the gospel of God's grace which is Christ crucified for the reconciling of the world back unto God through Christ's shed blood; the sufficient payment to God for forgivenss of the world's trespasses (sins).
2 Corinthians 5:19

To wit, that God was in Christ, reconciling the world unto himself, not imputing their trespasses unto them; and hath committed unto us the word of reconciliation.

Romans 5:8-11

But God commendeth his love toward us, in that, while we were yet sinners, Christ died for us.
9 Much more then, being now justified by his blood, we shall be saved from wrath through him.
10 For if, when we were enemies, we were reconciled to God by the death of his Son, much more, being reconciled, we shall be saved by his life.
11 And not only so, but we also joy in God through our Lord Jesus Christ, by whom we have now received the atonement.

Notice what faith it is below that Paul states we are to have today to satisfy God's requirement for salvation:
1 Corinthians 15:1-4

Moreover, brethren, I declare unto you the gospel which I preached unto you, which also ye have received, and wherein ye stand;
2 By which also ye are saved, if ye keep in memory what I preached unto you, unless ye have believed in vain.
3 For I delivered unto you first of all that which I also received, how that Christ died for our sins according to the scriptures;
4 And that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures:

We are to believe that "Christ died for our sins", that He was buried, but rose again on the third day.  It is when we believe this truth that we are then sealed by and with the holy Spirit unto the day of redemption.
Ephesians 1:12-13

That we should be to the praise of his glory, who first trusted in Christ.
13 In whom ye also trusted, after that ye heard the word of truth, the gospel of your salvation: in whom also after that ye believed, ye were sealed with that holy Spirit of promise,

Ephesians 4:30

And grieve not the holy Spirit of God, whereby ye are sealed unto the day of redemption.

When we finally place our faith in the completed work of Jesus Christ for us, we have a new spiritual position with God.  We are adopted by Him for eternity and have been gifted all spiritual blessings in heavenly places (Eph 1:3-5). We are "made the righteousness of God" upon having this faith in Christ (2 Cor 5:21).  God no longer sees who we see when we look in the mirror, He now sees Christ in us.
With these truths in mind, does it make sense to ask God for forgiveness of our sins...when He already forgave the world?  Are we not overlooking Christ on the cross by asking for forgiveness?  Asking God for forgiveness would indicate that we have yet to believe (put our faith in) what God completed for us through Christ because of His love.  We are attempting to take some of the credit (glory) for our salvation, but salvation is the gift of God offered by His grace.
Ephesians 2:8-9

For by grace are ye saved through faith; and that not of yourselves: it is the gift of God:
9 Not of works, lest any man should boast.

There is nothing wrong with having a direct conversation with God once we are in Christ.  Confession of sin indicates that we may need some help in removing sin from our lives, but it would be wise to thank God for the forgiveness of those sins through Christ rather than ask for forgiveness of them.
Colossians 3:15-17

And let the peace of God rule in your hearts, to the which also ye are called in one body; and be ye thankful.
16 Let the word of Christ dwell in you richly in all wisdom; teaching and admonishing one another in psalms and hymns and spiritual songs, singing with grace in your hearts to the Lord.
17 And whatsoever ye do in word or deed, do all in the name of the Lord Jesus, giving thanks to God and the Father by him.

Romans 8:35-39

Who shall separate us from the love of Christ? shall tribulation, or distress, or persecution, or famine, or nakedness, or peril, or sword?
36 As it is written, For thy sake we are killed all the day long; we are accounted as sheep for the slaughter.
37 Nay, in all these things we are more than conquerors through him that loved us.
38 For I am persuaded, that neither death, nor life, nor angels, nor principalities, nor powers, nor things present, nor things to come,
39 Nor height, nor depth, nor any other creature, shall be able to separate us from the love of God, which is in Christ Jesus our Lord.


Seriously, this answer has been truly enlightening. Two things that stand out and have blown my mind: God no longer imputes our sins to us—how can I keep forgetting this? And second: instead of focusing on sin, focus on the overabundant grace that has already forgiven it. You haven't given me a recipe; you've gone straight to the heart of the matter: thank you so much for this beautiful answer!

It is the truth that is beautiful, but thank you sincerely!

@Ian This sets forth a universal redemption, assuming Christ died for the sins of all humans. This is not the Reformed perspective which recognises that Christ died for the sins of his own people. Who those people are is revealed when they repent, *confessing their sins and believe the gospel. This misapplies 'reconciliation' (apokatallasso) which is a matter of sin itself from Adam to all his seed and applies it to sins, which are individual trangressions requiring penitence, confession and justification. The question rightly recognised a place for confession in Reformed theology.

@NigelJ The universe was redeemed, as is clear per scripture. Salvation is open to anyone who will simply believe.  The Philippian jailer asked "what must I do for salvation?" Paul did not say to hope you are one of God's chosen.  He said to "believe on the Lord Jesus Christ and you will be saved". Yes, believers are chosen, but that is based on God's foreknowledge of us all.  1 Peter 1:2
"Elect according to the foreknowledge of God the Father, through sanctification of the Spirit, unto obedience and sprinkling of the blood of Jesus Christ: Grace unto you, and peace, be multiplied."

@NigelJ You put confessing in bold. You must believe that Paul preaches the same gospel as Peter, James, and John. Can you show me where in Paul's thirteen epistles (Romans through Philemon) that Paul says how to get our sins forgiven? You are not able, and it is because our sins WERE forgiven through Christ's shed blood for the world.  If confession, asking for forgiveness, water baptism, etc...were a requirement for the church, the body of Christ in this Ephesians 3:2 'age of Gods grace' then boasting would be an issue. Believers can only boast in the work of Christ...not ourselves.

@MarkVestal As I pointed out, above, you are not presenting the Reformed position. P.S. In Romans, Paul is addressing 'all ... beloved of God ... called saints'. He does not tell them how their sins are to be forgiven . . . they are already justified.

@NigelJ I agree.

You agree ? But the question asked for a Reformed Perspective. Are you admitting to not answering the question ?

@NigelJ I agree that they are already justified upon having faith.

@NigelJ Thank you for your input. You are right that my question concerns Reformed theology. I need to review what you mentioned about reconciliation (Adam) and sin. I understand it as the distinction between originating original sin (Gen 2:17 and 3:1 ff) and the sin we continue to commit (?) after justification.

@Ian Yes. Sin, as such, sin in flesh as a consequence of sin coming into the world. And sins committed, personally, actions. I prefer the rendering 'restoration' to 'reconciliation'. See my book Redemption and Restoration Belmont Publications. (Free of charge online.) See my profile for the website address.

@NigelJ I've been trying to download the book but for some reason the link doesn't work!

@Ian Thank you for pointing that out. The other ones are OK. I shall contact the Web Host who looks after it for me. In the meantime I can email you a PDF if you send your email to my business address (on my profile). Regards.

@Ian The link is now fixed. Thank you, again, for reporting this. Kind Regards,

@NigelJ Thank you so much! Apologies for my late response.

Thank you .. . . . .@Ian

There is an often-overlooked truth about Protestantism, which is that Luther did not abolish private confession. While those brought up Protestant often do not feel the same need to for private confession that is hammered into Roman Catholics, (good) Protestant pastors will still hear private confessions and offer private absolution. I encourage you to speak to your pastor about this matter and to continue to make use of private confession as you feel it is beneficial to you. Frankly, us Protestants would probably do well to make more use of private confession than we do.

Is contrition and a sincere confession enough?

As far as I understand, most Protestants would say "yes", but again, there is benefit in confessing to a pastor and receiving absolution from a mortal agent (i.e. physically hearing the words as opposed to receiving absolution only in Spirit). Understand, however, that "formal" confession doesn't have greater salvific power; what it offers is greater comfort.
Hopefully that helps with your question. Now, if you'll pardon me, I need to object to Mark V's Answer...

Does it make sense to ask God for forgiveness of our sins... when He already forgave the world? Are we not overlooking Christ on the cross by asking for forgiveness?

In response, I will also quote Scripture:

8If we say we have no sin, we deceive ourselves, and the truth is not in us. 9If we confess our sins, he is faithful and just to forgive us our sins and to cleanse us from all unrighteousness. (1 John 1)

The idea that we don't need to acknowledge our guilt is clearly nonsense. It that the same as asking for forgiveness? Well, consider how the Lord Himself taught us to pray:

And forgive us our trespasses (Matthew 6:12)

We have explicit instruction to pray for forgiveness. It doesn't get much clearer than that. Now, that said, it's true we're praying for what has, in a very certain sense, already been granted, and we must take care not to fall into the trap of believing that our own actions, even in merely asking for forgiveness, are somehow of merit in themselves. (Scripture also teaches that, on our own, we cannot repent, and that it is the Spirit working in us that makes repentance possible.) Nevertheless, the idea that we shouldn't ask God for what we need, whether food, guidance, or forgiveness, is misguided. Yes, in a sense, God has already granted us all these things, but Scripture teaches that He still wants us to ask for them.
Nor are our Lord's words the end of the matter:

Confess your sins to one another and pray for one another, that you may be healed. (James 5:16)

Scripture also records examples of believers confessing in Matthew 3:6 / Mark 1:5 and in Acts 19:18.
Therefore, my advice is this: When you attend Divine Service, confess and ask for forgiveness along with everyone else; the reason it's properly called Divine Service and not "worship" is because you are being served by God when you receive absolution and the Eucharist. (And if your church doesn't have "Divine Service"... find one that does.) Whenever you are troubled by sin, stop and pray for forgiveness and be assured that you are — that, as Mark points out, you already have been — forgiven. If you are especially troubled, seek private confession with your pastor. I would also encourage regularly praying for forgiveness (e.g. every night) even if nothing is particularly troubling you.
Again, however, understand that you aren't doing these things to "earn" salvation, but because they help build your relationship with God.

I appreciate your gracious objection to my answer. It is refreshing!  I would agree with your answer if we today were believing Hebrews, who await the arrival of their promised earthly kingdom of heaven of priests to the world, but because we are the heavenly assembly of believers, the church, the body of Christ, I also graciously object to your answer. Some day we will all become one family, but not for a while.  Ephesians 1:10 "That in the dispensation of the fulness of times he might gather together in one all things in Christ, both which are in heaven, and which are on earth; even in him:"

@matthew You are right that Luther did not abolish the private practice. And you are right that, in my opinion, this practice has been somewhat lost in the Protestant environment. You have perfectly explained the issue of comfort in the matter of confession, thank you. I believe that confession has an aspect of making sin public and bringing it to light that is very beneficial, but it is possible that I still have some 'Catholic hangover,' so to speak, and am confusing doctrines.

@matthew Personally, I have to say that confessing my guilt before the Lord helps me a lot to obey Him more closely. It feels very strange to abandon something like that; considering, of course, as has been rightly pointed out, that this does not add any salvific component on my part.

@Ian, Protestantism is very diverse, and some have (IMO) "thrown out the baby with the bathwater". There is much in Roman Catholicism that is problematic — excessive focus on Mary and the Saints, loss of Sola Scriptura and Sola Gratia — but also much that is good, such as traditional worship. The Latin Mass, for example, is only "bad" because, at the time, most people didn't understand it. I would still argue that reading the Word and/or preaching in Latin is a problem, but chanting the liturgy in Latin is fine if you understand it, which is much more possible for modern, literate audiences.

If you find a practice useful... keep it! So long as you are rightly discerning between what is necessary and what is merely beneficial (and correctly avoiding what is distracting, e.g. the aforementioned Marianism), I see no problem. (You didn't mention which Protestant denomination you're leaning toward, but if it isn't obvious, I have pretty strong inclinations to the "high church" side of Protestantism. It also... annoys me to hear about Protestants citing a desire for "high church" as a reason for becoming Catholic, as if Roman Catholics have a monopoly on that... )

@Matthew I don't disagree with you, but I don't share your point. Understanding is not the same as comprehending. There are many aspects of faith that I can read about, yet they surpass my understanding. Additionally, for a Catholic, the liturgy operates on the principle of ex opere operato and ex opere operantis, so there is no point in knowing latin in order to participate in the sacrament.

@Matthew I am interested in the Reformed perspective, especially Presbyterian, but I do not rule out the others. There are points with Lutheranism that I do not share. That is why I distinguish between mere Protestantism and the Reformed vision. But I am open to other points of view that you want to share with me!
